# Update dashboard on element click in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling

[Please Click Here To See My Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6Qn4.jpg)

I want to do one-click on the list in the table right side, then my left side is the dashboard that will show all information of the list I clicked. Those elements in the dashboard are all connecting to API.

My question is, which method is better to do one-click on the table element and then update all components in the dashboard such as bar and chart. I have researched some and can't find much example, should I use router or some other method?

Sorry, first time using vue.js and create web app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by throwing an event from the child component `i.e` the table to the parent component that is the dashboard.

Then the dashboard will register that event and make an **API** call and change the props passed to all the components like graph etc.

You can learn more about events from child component to parent component over here:- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Answer (score 0):

No need to use routes or any other method in my opinion. You can use table on cell click method (which will have the cell params) and call your api's inside the method. It won't be an issue. Do revert back in case of problems